# Prime numbers up to n in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a program which prints prime numbers up to n.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#g').click(function(){ 
                var n = $('#a').val();
                for (a=2; a<n; a++) {
                    for (i=2; i<a; i++) {
                        if (a%i=0) {
                            break
                        }
                    } else {
                        var r = $('#r').html(); 
                        $('#r').html(r+'<br />'+i); 
                    }
                }
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your code the checking modulus have some error. `if (a%i=0)` if condition needs `==` to checking. single `=` is storing the value. Also semicolon missing after `break` in next line. There is an unwanted closing bracket also. I have removed the else condition and set a variable `ct=0`. And print the data when it becomes 1, that is set in condition.
Please check the below code for more reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#g').click(function(){ 
     var n = $('#a').val();
         for(a=2;a<=n;a++){
                ct=0;
                 for(j=2;j<a;j++){
                      if(a%j==0){   //checking whether num is dvisible by j
                         ct=1;  
                         break;
                         }
                    }
            if(ct==0){   //if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime
                 var r = $('#r').html(); 
                 $('#r').html(r+'<br />'+j); 
            }
         }
  });  
});
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="limit" id="a">
        <button id="g">Go</button>
        <div id="r"></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a proper explanation. A statement like *"You May Check it"* is meaningless. People shouldn't have to manually compare each line to look for differences either

Comment: OK. I will do it. Thanks for your advice.